# how to remove line if the subsequent line have the same initial current line

Tags: sed

if i have a list as below:

```
cat mytext
name first_Aelement
loc second_Aelement
cell third_Alement
name first_Belement
loc second_Belement
loc second_Belement_1
cell third_Blement
name first_Celement
loc second_Celement
cell third_Clement
```

how could i filter the lines with same header as previous line.  expected output is:

```
cat mytext
name first_Aelement
loc second_Aelement
cell third_Alement
name first_Belement
loc second_Belement
cell third_Blement
name first_Celement
loc second_Celement
cell third_Clement
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `awk` should do:

```
awk 'NR>1 && $0~a {f=1} !f; {a=$1;f=0}' file
name first_Aelement
loc second_Aelement
cell third_Alement
name first_Belement
loc second_Belement
cell third_Blement
name first_Celement
loc second_Celement
cell third_Clement
```

It test to see if current line does contain the previous line, if so, do not print it.
Skip the first line, since it will be different from previous line.

Comment: `a=$0` should be `a=$1`

Comment: @BMW You are correct, fixed. `lines with same header`

Comment: @BMW I think you should consider removing the comment once Jotne solved it. Otherwise it looks like the error persists.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n '1h;1!H;x;s/\(\n\)\(.*\)\1\2.*/\1\2/;x;${x;p;}' YourFile
```

hope your file is not millions lines because it is kept in buffer memory :-)

look at each line if starting like the previous (last of buffer) and dont keep it in this case (replace by nothing). At the end, print the result